# How to specify the complete path for a resource file when accessing it in Sharepoint object model?

Tags: 2010, resource-files

I followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/11/29/sharepoint-2010-localization-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) tutorial to create a resource file named `GlobalResources.resx` under `Resources`.

[image: Resources file in root]

I am able to access the content of the resource file using:

```
string resourceVal = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:GlobalResources, ResourceKey", 
"GloablResources", language);
```

However, to follow company coding standards, I am required to move the resources file into a folder named `<client>.<project>.<department>.<farm|sandbox>`.
So I did this:

[image: Resource file in sub-folder]

But now I'm not able access the resource values!

I tried the following...

(a)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm/GlobalResources, ResourceKey", 
"Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm/GlobalResources", language);
```

(b)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources, ResourceKey", 
"Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources", language);
```

(c)

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GlobalResources, ResourceKey", 
"Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GlobalResources", language);
```

...but none of them worked.

***How do I access the resource file that's not in the root of the `Resources` folder?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:YourKeyValue", "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GloablResources", 1033);
```

plz refer this link
http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/12/14/how-to-create-multilingual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

did you try this $Resources:Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\GlobalResources  or $Resources:`/Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm/GlobalResources?

also check this msdn for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx

check this guy http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/07/using-resource-files-resx-when-developing-sharepoint-solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The folder becomes part of the namespace. I think you are almost there with option c), but as first parameter write the key "$Resources: ResourceName".

For example if in the resource file you have key-value pair with name = "MyFieldName" and value="MyField" then this should work:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyFieldName", "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GloablResources", language);
```

And don't forget to run copyappbincontent command.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, but sorry, specifying the resource filename as `Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm.GlobalResources` didn't work for me. Instead, `Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\GlobalResources` did.